# How to use value of a cell once?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a certain cell (e.g. C1) that is computed by some formula and another cell (e.g. C2) that when a IF event happens, it takes the value of cell C1.

But, I only want to have C2's value be calculated one initial time and from then on, C2's value will stay the same and no longer depend on C1.

Is that possible, and if so, how can I do that?

If I wasn't clear enough, [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oaf357hJPvpEcENw7pgaay4LR6rUprKbpbLAeWnrln0/edit#gid=0) is an example spreadsheet with the logic commented.

Comment: Write a script function to check the value and if not default, then overwrite it with the new value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer: a simple copy script can do the job:

```
function simpleCopy() { 
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //access to the spreadsheet
 SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('testing enviroment')); //access to the sheet by name
 var range = sheet.getRange('D1'); //assign the range you want to copy
 var copy = range.getValues();
 sheet.getRange('D2').setValue(copy) //new range you want to paste a value
}
```